# Convert string containing wildcards to regexp

Tags: regex, pcregrep

I need to convert string containing wildcards with a regexp.

For example, if I have an input string like below:

> ab*dd*c

This means

> ab(any number of any characters)d(any number of any characters)c

Where `any character` is any alphanumeric character or '_'.

I've tried something like below:

> 'ab([[:alnum]] | '_')*dd([[:alnum]] | '_')*c'

But, as you can see, for, example, `([[:alnum]] | '\_')*` matches `d` also, and, so, I couldn't get needed match.

What comes to mind is use something like below:

> 'ab[^ d]*dd[^ c]*c'

Is there another better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/ab\w*?dd\w*?c/
```

`\w*?` will match any **alphanumeric character or _** non-greedy.

Comment: yes, but my question is different. With your regex  this `[\p{L}_]*` will match `dd` also, and we'll not get the needed match.

Comment: Thanks, @anubhava, it's working. I meant that this `([[:alnum]] | '_')*` part of regex matches the whole word, and therefore, `dd` is not being matched.

Comment: Even that can be written as: `[[:alnum:]_]*?` but `\w*?` is shorter.

Comment: `[[:alnum:]_]*?` is not working, but `\w*?` is ok :)